# GWT JUnit change browser

Tags: gwt

I need to run my Unit tests on the google chrome browser, because I use some special HTML5 features.

The problem is that the tests are always running in FF3!!

`Starting http://127.0.1.1:53554/com.yyy/junit-standards.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.1.1:54766 on browser FF3`

I already changed the eclipse web browser, but this doesn't make any effect.

Yes, I know I can test it in any browser with manualRun, but is really su...!

Do you know a way to change the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works.

http://totalprogus.blogspot.com/2009/11/eclipse-gwtexternalbrowser.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like the options are limited to emulating FF3, IE6, and IE7 (as of GWT 2.4). The only other ways are manual and remote testing.

To test as IE7, add this to your JVM args for your test (in Eclipse, under the debug/run profile for your junits): `-Dgwt.args="-runStyle HtmlUnit:IE7"`

See also: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideTestingRemoteTesting

(Posting this because it's what I was looking for, and hopefully it will help someone else.